Inserting a Select into a larger select
So I have the simple base query below.
select 
TransNo as 'Transaction No.',
Status as 'Status',
CliNam as 'Account Holder Name',
PayType as 'Receipt Type',
Amount/100 AS 'Total',
InputDateTime as 'Amount Input date',
InputBy as 'Input by',
AuthorisedBy As 'Authorised By',
ReleasedBy As 'Released By'
from Single_Queues
order by InputDateTime asc

However I need to add the below in to form an additional column in the above query.
select 
    STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + CAST([Comment] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM Single_Queues_Comments I
    WHERE (I.TransNo = O.TransNo) and I.CommentNo = 1
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,1,'') as 'Full Name'
from 
    Single_Queues_Comments O
group by 
    TransNo

How can this be done?
I tried the below but with no joy.
select 
TransNo as 'Transaction No.',
Status as 'Status',
CliNam as 'Account Holder Name',
(select 
    STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + CAST([Comment] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM Single_Queues_Comments I
    WHERE (I.TransNo = O.TransNo) and I.CommentNo = 1
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,1,'')
from 
    Single_Queues_Comments O
group by 
    TransNo) as 'Full Name',
PayType as 'Receipt Type',
Amount/100 AS 'Total',
InputDateTime as 'Amount Input date',
InputBy as 'Input by',
AuthorisedBy As 'Authorised By',
ReleasedBy As 'Released By'
from Single_Queues
order by InputDateTime asc


I remove the tag [tag:mysql], because you tagged ssms, so I draw the conclusion you are using sql-server, and not MySQL

Side note, don't use single quotes (') for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They have some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you must delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets ([]), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (").

Why are you using the old FOR XML PATH method? Are you not on a recent version of SQL Server?

Which "no joy" are you experiencing ? Please share more details.

The error received is below, the sub query and original query work fine by themselves in isolation, it is only trying to combine them I then experience said error -------- Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

BTW: Info about the error should be added to the question (using [edit])

Sorry, need more info, not reproduceable, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/ixPaj75Z

You generate multiple rows in the XML part of your query,also,its nto correlated to the transno of the outermost table.

Your inner query doesn't correlate with anything, it should be something along the lines of:
select 
TransNo as 'Transaction No.',
Status as 'Status',
CliNam as 'Account Holder Name',
STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + CAST([Comment] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    FROM Single_Queues_Comments I
    WHERE I.TransNo = sq.TransNo and I.CommentNo = 1
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,1,'')
as 'Full Name',
PayType as 'Receipt Type',
Amount/100 AS 'Total',
InputDateTime as 'Amount Input date',
InputBy as 'Input by',
AuthorisedBy As 'Authorised By',
ReleasedBy As 'Released By'
from Single_Queues sq
order by InputDateTime asc

